# List page for Polls

Tags: views, polls

I've put a Poll block on my home page using Views.  I want visitors to be able to see older polls, so I made a view for that as well that points to `/polls`.  However, this page displays each poll's voting form or results, depending on what the user has voted on.

I would like to reduce what is displayed for each node on this page to the linked title and `$submitted`... how can this be achieved?  I would also like to include the number of votes in `$submitted`.